# Where can I find the language files in Flash CS5.5 on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, adobe-flash, language-pack

I'm stuck with a Swedish version of Flash CS5.5 (legally licenced of course), but really need to get the language changed to English, as all my students are on English versions.

It was previously fairly easy to change most of the language setup in Flash CS5, but I'm having a harder time figuring out how to do it in the new CS5.5.

So, does anyone have a clue where to find the language files?
Would appreciate some help with it, as it really is a pain in the neck to use the Swedish version....